# libFlurryAnalytics.a error

Tags: iphone, compiler-errors

I have a code from my senior developer that i have to modify. Changes were done successfully and it runs well on the simulator. However the moment i run it on the device, it gives the following error.

"ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/victorray/Desktop/MaxfashionRetailiPhone/MaxfashionRetailiPhone/libFlurryAnalytics.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

I tried searching hard for a solution, but couln't find one. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go go Build Settings of project and there remove armv7s from Valid architecture or download new libFlurryAnalytics.a which is build for iOS 6.x

Comment: Thank you so much robin. Its working now. The removal of armv7s from the valid architechtures dint work... but the other othion did. thanks a lot.. you saved my day :)

Comment: its my pleasure ScarletWitch